# Lights flickering in multiple rooms

Tags: electrical, switch, light-fixture, light

This morning the lights in my living room stopped working, along with my bedroom lights flickering however lamps work when plugged into an outlet now connected to a switch, any ideas?

Comment: Is it just those lights or is other stuff acting funny?  Do the lights act differently if a 240v range or dryer is on?  For now I will assume just those lights and have you turn off the breaker/s for them.  Might just be a loose connection in the circuit, but loose connections can heat up too much can cause major problems.  If comfortable working on circuits with the breakers off, you can check for loose connections.

Answer (score 4):

Probably a loose connection, which means something somewhere is arcing. If you can isolate which circuits are affected it would be wise to shut them off at the breaker panel until the problem is found, as this is the sort of thing that can lead to a structure fire, started by the arc.

If it's just one or two circuits it's probably inside the house. If (in North American 120/240 split-phase distribution) it appears to be affecting roughly half the house, it may be outside on the service connection wires, in which case you call your power company to come check the line connections.